# IOS problem with apache and range request

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following problem. When i add "RequestHeader unset Range" to my .htaccess I can view and open .pdf files on my website. But if I do so IOS devices can no longer access videos on my website, the video wont play. If I remove "RequestHeader unset Range" the videos work again but the pdf files do not.
Unfortunatelly my hoster changed something. Before everything was running fine.
Any idea how to fix this?

I tried the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(PDF|pdf)$">
    RequestHeader unset Range
</FilesMatch>
```

But it does not work when i add the FilesMatch rule.

My request looks like this:

```
"GET": {
    "scheme": "https",
    "host": "domain.de",
    "filename": "/de/user/recipe_pdf/2",
}

"Status": "416Requested Range Not Satisfiable",
"Version": "HTTP/2",
"Übertragen": "372 B (0 B Größe)",
"Referrer Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"

{
"Antwortkopfzeilen (372 B)": {
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "accept-ranges",
            "value": "bytes"
        },
        {
            "name": "cache-control",
            "value": "max-age=0, must-revalidate, private"
        },
        {
            "name": "content-disposition",
            "value": "inline; filename=\"recipes.pdf\""
        },
        {
            "name": "content-length",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "content-range",
            "value": "bytes */972493"
        },
        {
            "name": "content-type",
            "value": "application/pdf"
        },  
        {
            "name": "server",
            "value": "nginx"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^.*/recipe_pdf/.*#">
    RequestHeader unset Range
</If>
```